# Android AlertDialog crashes with NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I try to put HTML into a Listviewitem in an AlertDialog.
Therefore i found some snippet and finally set all together with my AlertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Onlineliste");

            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View convertView2 = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.costumdialog, null);
            builder.setView(convertView2);
            ListView lv = (ListView)convertView2.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.costumdialog, names)
                    {
                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                        {
                            View row;

                            if (null == convertView) {
                            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costumdialog, null);
                            } else {
                            row = convertView;
                            }

                            TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.singlerow);
                            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
                            //tv.setText(getItem(position));

                            return row;
                        }

                    };
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

The problem is, that the `setAdapter()` forces the app to crash with NullPointerException

The xml files etc. do all exist and there is no problem with them I think.

Can anyone help me?

Edit:

```
    06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at com.flipflopdev.epvp_aj1987_chat.ChatActivity$1$1.getView(ChatActivity.java:82)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2075)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1476)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1339)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2141)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1206)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2666)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-12 07:26:45.537: E/AndroidRuntime(28036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

R.layout.costumdialog

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

line 82 in ChatActivity

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
```

customtextrow.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singlerow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

New code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Onlineliste");

            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            //final View convertView2 = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.costumdialog, null);
            //builder.setView(convertView2);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.costumdialog, names)
                    {
                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                        {
                            View row;

                            if (null == convertView) {
                            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
                            } else {
                            row = convertView;
                            }

                            TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.singlerow);
                            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
                            //tv.setText(getItem(position));

                            return row;
                        }

                    };
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    ListView lv = (ListView)alert.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter); 


            alert.show();
```

Comment: post the error and R.layout.costumdialog,..

Comment: are you sure you have customListView view inside costumdialog layout?

Comment: what is **`(null == convertView)`** ??? it should be ` if (convertView == null)`

Comment: @Prag's you sure about that.. its the same

Comment: @Prag's there is no difference.both are same..

Comment: i don't think so!! if **NO**.. please explain..

Comment: Sounds like `lv` is `null`...

Comment: @Prag's there is nothing to explain. null checking can done in any of the above ways.

Comment: @Prag's try it Object i = null; if(null == i)

Comment: unless you post the stackrace and indicate the line where NPE occurs its difficult to solve your problem

Comment: Ohhkey... Thanks for the knowledge...Cheers...

Comment: @Phil post the R.layout.costumdialog and what is in Line 82 of ChatActivity

Comment: @Phil indicate line 82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `costomdialog.xml` does not have a `TextView` with id `singlerow`. Hence `tv` is null and when you call setText leads to `NullPointerException`.

From your comments it looks like singlerow is a layout with textview with

So Change this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.costumdialog, names)
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.singlerow, names)
```

Edit:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.customtextrow.xml, names)
```

Complete Example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 String names[]={"A","B","C"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Onlineliste");

    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View convertView2 = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.costomdialog, null);
    builder.setView(convertView2);
    ListView lv = (ListView)convertView2.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.costomdialog, names)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                {
                    View row;

                    if (null == convertView) {
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtextrow, null);
                    } else {
                    row = convertView;
                    }

                    TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.singlerow);
                    tv.setText(names[position]);
                    //tv.setText(getItem(position));

                    return row;
                }

            };
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
     }
   }
```

The xml are the same no changes

Snap:

[image]

Edit 2:

> why does the Html.fromHtml not work? :/ See my names ArrayList final
>   ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
>      String[]
>   splitted = response.split("\|");                 for(String name:splitted) {
>                     names.add(Html.fromHtml("" + name.split("\+")[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeX96.png) + "").toString());                 }

Split the String add it to arraylist. Set the html while setting text to textview.

Comment: single row is in another xml file :o

Comment: @Phil is single row a layout with textview?

Comment: Yes like the Listview in the R.layout.costumdialog, I tried it now but it just closes the app *confusing*

Comment: @Phil check the edit and post `singlerow.xml`. Confrimation of what you ahve

Comment: Still NullPointerException, Error in line 89: `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` For costumtextrow.xml see edit above

Comment: @Phil `lv` can't be null. if line 89 is that line it looks like `lv` is null.

Comment: Yes but I don't know why. I also tried the answer of Rod_Algonquin but there the same error appears

Comment: @Phil no way lv can be null. you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Phil check the edit now. You have commented the code where you inflate the layout. What else do you expect

Comment: finally its working! :) but why does the Html.fromHtml not work? :/ See my names ArrayList `final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] splitted = response.split("\\|");
    for(String name:splitted) {
     names.add(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + name.split("\\+")[1] + "</u>").toString());
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55482/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-phil).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are inflating `R.layout.costumdialog` without any TextView you dont need to inflate ListView inside a ListView you just need to add TextView into the `R.layout.costumdialog`

Create a new layout called `text.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singlerow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

change it to this

```
if (null == convertView) {
     row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
```

That is not the right way to set the adapter to the `ListView` you need to get the `ListView` reference from the AlertDialog to enable it to use the adapter.

**example:**

**wrong**

```
      ListView lv = (ListView)convertView2.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
```

**right**

```
   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
   ListView lv = (ListView)alert.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
```

full code:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Onlineliste");

        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View convertView2 = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.costumdialog, null);
        builder.setView(convertView2);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        ListView lv = (ListView)alert.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.text, names)
                {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                    {
                        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.singlerow);
                        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
                        //tv.setText(getItem(position));

                        return row;
                    }

                };
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        alert.show();
```

Comment: App still crashes when I do `.setAdapter` after ListView findingViewById

Comment: see the edit under "new code" R.layout.text looks exactly like you wrote

Comment: Ouh the first inflating is still important? I'm confused I thought it might be wrong. But still crash in line `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` :(

Comment: @Phil post R.layout.costumdialog

Comment: @Phil done it should work now. see my edit full code

Comment: Rag's code worked for me so I do not want to change it again :o :D But many thanks to you for your help! Upvote given!

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the inflater,

```
final View convertView2 = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.costumdialog, null);
```

you are casting the view which is not required.

try something like this

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog() {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(TicTacToe.this)
            //.setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
            .setTitle(getTitleText())
            .setView(textEntryView)
            .setPositiveButton("JOIN GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    try
                    {
                        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
                            playerName = et.getText().toString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            })
            .create();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the quesiton